# Event hits must be sent after a pageview hit, but this event hit was not preceded by a pageview

Tags: google-analytics

I've an ecommerce site and I'm tracking the Orders in the Thank-you page sending all the transaction data within the DataLayer variable.

The transaction data is been sent and recorded but I'm getting this error message when debugging with Tag Assitant Chrome Extention:

> Event hits must be sent after a pageview hit, but this event hit was
>   not preceded by a pageview

[image]

**HTML of Thank-you page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Stickers Gallito Perú">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="fGkwUY2RcijkVzB6DiwIuAToP1y5xw8ECXQQabRAOIM"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Stickers Gallito</title>



    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'eec.purchase',
            ecommerce: {
                currencyCode: 'PEN',
                purchase: {
                    actionField: {
                        id: 5,
                        affiliation: 'Stickers Gallito E-Commerce',
                        revenue: 250.00,
                        shipping: 15.00,
                        coupon: ''
                    },
                    products: JSON.parse('[{"id": 5, "sku": "S5", "name": "Stickers cuadrados", "price": "250.00", "size": "3cm x 3cm", "quantity": 1}]')
                },

            }
        });
    </script>




    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-TPXWL88');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->



</head>
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TPXWL88"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

#Rest of HTMl body...
```

**I thought that the DataLayer should be before the Google Analytics code, Am I wrong? Or How should I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

The dataLayer can be filled before the GTM script, but an event is best associated to a yet fired pageview (not mandatory but recommended).

You could associate your e-commerce data to a pageview instead of an event, and remove the part `event: 'eec.purchase',` to do so.